# Node.js get open file descriptor count (development)

Tags: node.js

I'm using chokidar to watch files, and I get EMFILE errors, and I know that this happened because I have too many file descriptors currently open.

I'm using socket, so graceful-fs doesn't fix the problem. Also, setting my ulimit temporarily is, well, temporary.

Is there a way to get the number of file descriptors currently open in code? I want to check if the number is about to go over limit, and make the process wait before it continues watching files/directories.

Answer (score 9):

A simple way to get the current open fd count (assuming you have a `/proc` fs) is to check the number of entries in `/proc/self/fd`:

```
var readdir = require('fs').readdir;

readdir('/proc/self/fd', function(err, list) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(list.length);
});
```

Keep in mind, opening the directory for reading will incur another open fd.

If you want to check the number of open file descriptors from an external process, just replace `self` with the pid you want to check.